# NSIS Installer on Windows 10 triggers Bitdefender Ransomware detection

Tags: windows, macros, ms-office, nsis, controlled-folder-access

I am working currently on a software which I am packing into an NSIS installer and distribute the resulting exe file. The installer must run primarily on Windows 10. Since a few days, Bitdefender added protection against ransomware. Since my installer tries to write to the `Documents` folder for the current logged in user, the installer is being blocked by Bitdefener as potentially malicious. How can I fix this? Should I not write to the `Documents` folder? Is there another appropriate folder? Can I sign my installer or is there some other method that makes this installer trustworthy for Bitdefender?

The file which I am writing is an `.xlsm` file. While I agree that this is not the best file format to create in terms of security, this is the file format I am currently having and there is no quick way to change this.

Comment: I'm guessing the file is the problem and not NSIS? Does the .xlsm file actually contain macros?

Comment: Yes, after further investigating it seems that the problem is not NSIS but the xlsm file. Yes, it does contain macros which we unfortunately need at the moment.

Comment: What happens if you extract it as .txt and then rename? Rename from a batch file? You should probably remove the NSIS tag and replace it with MS-Office.